# Husband unplugged crockpo

Tags: chicken

Started cooking chicken in crock pot at 4 pm. I cooked until midnight.husband came downstairs and unplugged it. It cooled
on the counter until 8 a.m. this morning is my chicken still good? Or can I reboil it and making it a chicken salad?

Comment: Definitely, unambiguously not safe to eat. Not even in a gray area. Your chicken spent 8 hours in the temperature range between "hot" and "room temperature". It's not food anymore. Now it's a petri dish of bacteria and the toxic compounds those bacteria produce. Cooking it again will not get rid of the toxic compounds. Throw it out. Next time, put a big sign on the crock pot plug saying DO NOT UNPLUG.

Comment: @csk - that's just appalling 'scare tactics'. if it was cooked through properly in the first 8 hours & the lid left on, it's 99% chance to be perfectly good. The 1% is the reason such as the FDA have such strict guidelines.

Comment: @Tetsujin That would be a reasonable position if the chicken had sat in a sealed crock pot for several hours. But this chicken sat for *eight* hours. That's far, far beyond the point where you can say, "Well, *maybe* it's okay to eat."

Comment: No, it really isn't. It's far beyond what *might* be unsafe in an absolute "we're the government, responsible for the safety of all commercial kitchen output", but I'm pretty sure after 40 years of leaving out takeaways or any dinner I made too much of, to finish off for brunch, I've avoided the russian roulette long enough to claim empirically it's dramatically over-cautious.